# Find all occurrences of a string except if found within another pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have blocks of text like below where I am looking to find all occurrences of;

```
data ...;
...
run;
```

where ... can be any type of string pattern.  I want to only find occurences of this where the pattern is not within C style comments or if it is wrapped in another pattern like below.  I want to find all occurrences of;

```
data foo;
    set bar;
run;
```

but not

```
%macro x();
    data foo;
        set bar;
    run;
%mend;
```

or

```
/* data foo;*/
/* set bar;*/
/* run;*/
```

I have the following function which will exclude the pattern when wrapped in a comment or `%macro ... %mend` however it is only returning the last match and not each occurrence.  How can I adjust this to return every match as a list of lists with one list per block?  Thanks in advance.

```
s = """
/**
* @file
* @brief    Description of the program
*/

/**
* @macro    xyz
* @brief    Description of the Macro
*/
%macro xyz();
    data foo_nomatch;
        set bar;
    run;
%mend;

/**
* @data     foo_matchme
* @brief    Description of the DataStep
*/
data foo_matchme;
    set bar;
run;

# Should Not Match
/** 
* data foo_nomatch2;
*      set bar;
* run;
*/

/**
* @datastep:    foo2
* @brief:       This is a description.
*/
# Should match as a 2nd match
data foo_matchme2;
    set bar;
run;
"""
def datastep(s):
    t1 = 'data'
    t2 = 'run;'
    t3 = ';'
    e1 = re.escape('/**')
    e2 = re.escape('*/')
    e3 = re.escape('%macro')
    e4 = re.escape('%mend')

    return re.findall('%s.*%s|%s.*%s|(%s.*?%s)' %(e1,e2,e3,e4,t1,t2),s,re.DOTALL|re.IGNORECASE)

print(datastep(s))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `.*`-part of the skip-subregexes non-greedy, i.e., change `'%s.*%s|%s.*%s|(%s.*?%s)'` to `'%s.*?%s|%s.*?%s|(%s.*?%s)'`.

Demo:

```
for match in datastep(s):
    if match:
        print(match)
```

Output:

```
data foo_matchme;
    set bar;
run;
data foo_matchme2;
    set bar;
run;
```

Comment: I just found the same conclusion after posting.  Thanks!